# Pinescript nested if (or else if) condition evaluates crossunder() differently than if it had been calculated as a variable first

Tags: pine-script

So I'm coding up an indicator on pinescript.
I seem to be getting different behaviour with nested if statements between two ways of writing the same piece of code

- having the statement evaluated in the nested if condition itself
- precalculate the conditional statement and using a variable in the nested if condition

```
crossover  = crossover(tradeEntrySource, ind)
crossunder = crossunder(tradeEntrySource, ind)
```

```
  // use statement directly
  longStopLossCheck := if (not crossover)
      if (crossunder(tradeEntrySource, ind))
          true
      else
          false
```

vs

```
  // precalculate and use variable
  longStopLossCheck := if (not crossover)
      if (crossunder)
          true
      else
          false
```

```
plot(series=longStopLossCheck?3:2, title="longStopLossCheck", color = color.red)
plot(series=crossunder?2:1, title="crossunder", color = color.blue)
plot(series=crossover?1:0, title="crossover", color = color.green)
```

[image: Use crossunder() function in nested if statement]
[image: Use crossunder variable in nested if statement]

the first image shows what values are returned when i use the statement directly, and the second image is when i use a variable

I can't seem to figure out why i see different values / behaviour.
Any insights as to why this is happening?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Functions like `crossover()` need to be executed on each bar to return correct results, which will not be the case when they are called from within conditional blocks that prevent their execution on each bar. Pre-evaluating those functions prior to entry in the `if` structure is the solution.

See the [Pine User Manual on the subject](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Functions_and_annotations.html#execution-of-pine-functions-and-historical-context-inside-function-blocks), and a perhaps easier to understand [article from the PineCoders FAQ](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#why-do-some-functions-and-built-ins-evaluate-incorrectly-in-if-or-ternary--blocks) on the subject.

*Disclosure: the link in this answer points to a PineCoders FAQ entry. I am a member of the PineCoders community and I most probably wrote that FAQ entry. PineCoders is a TradingView-supported group of volunteer Pine coders and PineCoders' website is strictly educational. Neither TradingView nor PineCoders benefits financially from sending traffic to pinecoders.com, and the site contains no affiliate/referral links.*